# Datawindow Rowscopy Null error

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have 2 windows that has a data window. `dw_1` and `dw_2` is connected to `dw_main`. Now, everytime I run the program, pop up message shows

> error R0002. Null object reference at line 2

Please help me. What should I do so the data window won't confuse. Note, I am using one data object for the two datawindow.

```
if dw_1.rowcount( ) <> 0 then 
 dw_1.RowsCopy(1, dw_1.rowcount( ), Primary!,dw_2,  1, Primary!)
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like dw_2 is the null object.  You should also change your IF statement to " > 0" since a negative return from rowcount is  an error condition.

Comment: Thank you Sir Matt. It is okay now using  openwithparm.